# jupyter notebook doesn't remember pyLDAvis.prepare()

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

When executing the cell

```
pyLDAvis.sklearn.prepare(lda_tf, dtm_tf, tf_vectorizer)
```

it displays the graph but after saving the notebook and reopen it, it shows nothing.

I have the following imports/setting:

```
import pyLDAvis
import pyLDAvis.gensim
import pyLDAvis.sklearn
pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()
```

print(pyLDAvis.**version**) -> 2.1.2

Anaconda environment: Python 3.6 and ipython 7.2.0.

Thanks for the help.